# Error with the size of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I am now om the project [deeplab_v2](https://github.com/DrSleep/tensorflow-deeplab-resnet/tree/tf-0.11) which is supported at least by tf r0.11, but I only have r0.10 on my lab machine. So when I change some code to fit with the old version I meet the following question.

```
 if input_size is not None:
    h, w = input_size
    if random_scale:
        scale = tf.random_uniform([1], minval=0.75, maxval=1.25, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None)
        h_new = tf.to_int32(tf.mul(tf.to_float(tf.shape(img)[1]), scale))
        w_new = tf.to_int32(tf.mul(tf.to_float(tf.shape(img)[1]), scale))
        new_shape = tf.squeeze(tf.pack([h_new, w_new]), squeeze_dims=[1])

        img = tf.image.resize_images(img, new_shape)
```

here is the original code, and the `input_size` is [312 , 312], and the `tf.image.resize_image(img, [height, width])`is the function in tf r0.11.

But in the tf r0.10 the function is changed to `tf.image.size_image(img, height, width)`, so I don not know how to change the `new_shape` to TWO elements`[height , width]`.

Comment: Does `tf.image.resize_images(img, h_new, w_new)` work?

Comment: I have solved it by `new_shape[0], new_shape[1]`, thanks anyway